# Галерея из некоторого кол-ва изображений ModX Revolution

Tags: modx

На сайте макетом задуман ряд изображений, количество которых в идеале нужно менять в админке через TV поле.
Структура изображений выглядит как на скриншоте[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Важно заметить что по задумке будет добавляться не только изображение, но и "карточка" с подписью в которой это изображение лежит. 
 Если точнее, нужно, чтобы грубо говоря нажав на "Кнопка добавления" открывалось поле где нужно внести "Title" и добавить изображение, после чего "Ок", и например, из заранее подготовленного чанка с шаблоном для разметки этой галереи добавлялось изображение.

Есть ли какой-то уже предусмотренный способ самим ModX, или нужно будет самому выдумывать велосипед с костылями?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь отлично подойдет MIGX TV, в котором два поля - изображение и заголовок. Их количество гибко меняется, есть кнопка добавления, можно удалить, сортировать. На фронте при помощи сниппета getimagelist вывести с нужным чанком в требуемом шаблоне.

Comment: Несколько часов на чтение документации и обучающие ролики, и задача реализована, спасибо!)